# How do I inject a multiple interface service into a class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-6.0

Following [this example](https://medium.com/geekculture/advanced-dependency-injection-techniques-in-asp-net-core-3e6e9e0c541a) I can create a service with multiple interfaces

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<SweetAlert>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISweetAlert, SweetAlert>(implementationFactory: x => 
x.GetRequiredService<SweetAlert>());
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISweetAlert2, SweetAlert>(x => 
x.GetRequiredService<SweetAlert>());
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program));
```

But then how do I inject it into the class? Either I don't get it or the author doesn't address the situation.

Because it has two interfaces the usual constructor injection won't work.

Comment: You are registering everything as singletons, and mess up with providing several interfaces with one provider implementation. In your 'class' that will get two dependencies ISweetAlert and ISweetAlert2, do you want to get ONE and THE SAME object hidden under interface1 and interface2 (so have 1 implementation, 1 singleton, everything shared), or do you want to get TWO SEPARATE objects (so have 1 implementation, 2 separate singletons, impl shared, runtime separate)? And what do you mean by `usual constructor injection won't work`? IoCC should be able to handle that. What happens in your case?

Comment: You list two different interface types, why can't you declare a constructor that uses both different interfaces?

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. I am trying to follow the Interface Segregation Principle. When I want to do constructor injection it only takes 1 of the interfaces, as you would do normally. I want "ONE and THE SAME object hidden under interface1 and interface2 ". So that it looks like one interface

Comment: `When I want to do constructor injection it only takes 1 of the interfaces, as you would do normally` - nope. Constructor injection can take 2, 3, or 20 parameters. No problem. Just add `ISweetAlert foo` and `ISweetAlert2 bar` parameters to the ctor. Really. That's it. And your current code as shown should be able to launch 1 singleton, fully shared, providing 2 interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming no other problems in the code, injecting two (or more) dependencies to a component should be as simple as adding multiple parameters to its constructor

```
public class Foobarizer
{
    private readonly ISweetAlert alert1;
    private readonly ISweetAlert2 alert2;

    public Foobarizer(
        ISweetAlert alert1,
        ISweetAlert2 alert2
    )
    {
        this.alert1 = alert1;
        this.alert2 = alert2;
    }

    public void DoTheTrick()
    {
        this.alert1.Foo();
        this.alert2.Bar();
    }
}
```

For this, it doesn't matter where the instances of ISweetAlert and ISweetAlert2 come from. For this Foobarizer with 2 dependencies, they could be separate objects, they could be the same object, no difference. At least from Foobarizer's point of view.

For the container, there is a small difference, and that's why the article you cited provided a section on this special case of sharing a single singleton under two interfaces. But it doesn't impact (or: shouldn't impact but sometimes does (*)) how the Foobarizer looks like.

(*) that somewhat depends on the DI/IoCC library, but you probably use aspnet6's built-in one, so, it doesn't.